# October CMS no render requires Cache clear

Tags: octobercms

My October CMS site has developed a strange cache behaviour. When the cache has not been cleared for some time it renders a blank homepage.

Going to the backend and clearing the cache with the

Dashboard Cache Widget

CURRENT VERSION
1.0.1

AUTHOR
Flynsarmy

fixes the problem.

My cache config file is:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default cache connection that gets used while
| using this caching library. This connection is used when another is
| not explicitly specified when executing a given caching function.
|
*/

'default' => 'file',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Stores
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
| well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
| same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
|
*/

'stores' => [

    'apc' => [
        'driver' => 'apc'
    ],

    'array' => [
        'driver' => 'array'
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table'  => 'cache',
        'connection' => null,
    ],

    'file' => [
        'driver' => 'file',
        'path'   => storage_path().'/framework/cache',
    ],

    'memcached' => [
        'driver'  => 'memcached',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Key Prefix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
| be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
| value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
|
*/

'prefix' => 'october',

];
```

and the cache directory is 776.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm using OctoberCMS in all my projects since 6 months and never got this problem.
Anyway, try to remove cache with this command `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Thank you. This combined with disabling a route cache plugin solved it.